# Mana-toolkit installation problem

Tags: kali-linux

[image]

I'm reading this book:https://www.packtpub.com/networking-and-servers/learn-ethical-hacking-scratch

and in chapter 5 it talks about fake AP and mana-toolkit,
so i go to install it with the given command and it gives me this error.
Please help me if you can thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This error is not exclusive to Mana-toolkit, it tends to arise because your kali repositories/databases are not updated.

Please refer to the top answer of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean) question, which will hopefully help you understand how to fix this error.